# Transfer files from S3 to untrusted server via intermediary

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I have two servers that have an encrypted line of communication between them. One of these devices I trust with my AWS credentials and it can access files on my S3 bucket via boto or aws cli etc. The other one I do not trust with **any** aws credentials so normally it cannot access my files.

I am trying to come up with a way to get a file from S3 to the untrusted server but my best idea so far is to download the files to the trusted server and then send them to the other. Is there any better way to do this?

I don't want to use CDN or make my files public since I don't want anyone but the two servers to access them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate presigned URLs on the trusted servers and send those to the untrusted server that can then use those URLs to safely download the file. The URLs don't require the untrusted server to hold any keys. They also have a limited time-to-live so you can limit your exposure if those leak for some reason.

This way you can allow the untrusted server to access only the files you want for the period of time you want.

```
aws s3 presign s3://mybucket/myfile --expires-in 60
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could make specific IAM policies on demand that allowed access from the untrusted server to only the exact resources that were allowed

But TBH if the files aren't absolutely huge and/or don't change all the time then using the "trusted" server as a proxy is a good approach

Comment: IAM would definitely be a good solution but the untrusted server isn't going to be on Amazon. It's currently my laptop computer but I plan on moving to an intel NUC or raspberry pi 3 (whichever one I can free up). Is there an IAM-like approach to this that you know of?

Comment: You can create an IAM user with policies that allow it to only access specific files. You can then put the keys just for that user on your untrusted device. The policies can be edited using API at any time to avoid extended access.